# sequelize methods from association fooInstance.getBars() returning a wrong value

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js, associations

I've got 2 models with a many-to-many association through another model. By default, Sequelize creates instance methods for both models as you all may know (https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#special-methods-mixins-added-to-instances).

My problem is that the fooInstance.getBars() method and fooInstance.countBars() both return the wrong number of records.

The database was setup using sequelize migration files.

The 3 models are below.

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
      firstName: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    {}
  );
  User.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    User.belongsToMany(models.Week, {
      through: models.Roster,
      foreignKey: {
        name: "weekId"
      }
    });
  };
  return User;
};
```

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Week = sequelize.define(
    "Week",
    {
      date: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
      }
    },
    {}
  );
  Week.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Week.belongsToMany(models.User, {
      through: models.Roster,
      foreignKey: {
        name: "userId",
        allowNull: true
      }
    });
  };
  return Week;
};
```

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Roster = sequelize.define(
    "Roster",
    {
      weekId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: false
      },
      userId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
        unique: false
      }
    },
    {}
  );
  Roster.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return Roster;
};
```

Before I test out the methods, I created 1 record in weeks and 5 records in users then I created 5 associations using 5 Roster.create() in rosters.

When I do a query in my routes file like this `await Week.getUsers()`, instead of returning 5 users in an array, it returned 1 in an array. Similarly, the `await Week.countUsers()` code returned 1 instead of 5.

Please help!

Please let me know if I miss any important information.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the [docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#special-methods-mixins-added-to-instances) says:

> When an association is defined between two models, **the instances of those models gain special methods to interact with their associated counterparts**.

You are trying to call these special methods on Model class. Here is a working example:

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { Model, DataTypes, BelongsToManyGetAssociationsMixin, BelongsToManyCountAssociationsMixin } from 'sequelize';

class User extends Model {}
User.init(
  {
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'User' },
);

class Week extends Model {
  public getUsers!: BelongsToManyGetAssociationsMixin<User>;
  public countUsers!: BelongsToManyCountAssociationsMixin;
}
Week.init(
  {
    date: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'Week' },
);

class Roster extends Model {}
Roster.init(
  {
    weekId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: false,
    },
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      unique: false,
    },
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'Roster' },
);

User.belongsToMany(Week, { through: Roster, foreignKey: { name: 'weekId' } });
Week.belongsToMany(User, { through: Roster, foreignKey: { name: 'userId', allowNull: true } });

(async function test() {
  try {
    // create tables
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    // seed
    const week = await Week.create(
      {
        date: new Date(),
        Users: [
          { firstName: 'james' },
          { firstName: 'elsa' },
          { firstName: 'tim' },
          { firstName: 'lee' },
          { firstName: 'jasmine' },
        ],
      },
      { include: [User] },
    );
    // test
    const count = await week.countUsers();
    console.log('count:', count);
    const users = await week.getUsers();
    console.log('users count:', users.length);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

The execution results:

```sh
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Roster" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Week" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "User" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "User" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "User" ("id"   SERIAL , "firstName" VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'User' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Week" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Week" ("id"   SERIAL , "date" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'Week' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Roster" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Roster" ("weekId" INTEGER NOT NULL  REFERENCES "User" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, "userId" INTEGER  REFERENCES "Week" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, UNIQUE ("weekId", "userId"), PRIMARY KEY ("weekId","userId"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'Roster' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "Week" ("id","date") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "User" ("id","firstName") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "User" ("id","firstName") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "User" ("id","firstName") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "User" ("id","firstName") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "User" ("id","firstName") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "Roster" ("weekId","userId") VALUES ($1,$2) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "Roster" ("weekId","userId") VALUES ($1,$2) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "Roster" ("weekId","userId") VALUES ($1,$2) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "Roster" ("weekId","userId") VALUES ($1,$2) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "Roster" ("weekId","userId") VALUES ($1,$2) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): SELECT COUNT("User"."id") AS "count" FROM "User" AS "User" INNER JOIN "Roster" AS "Roster" ON "User"."id" = "Roster"."weekId" AND "Roster"."userId" = 1;
count: 5
Executing (default): SELECT "User"."id", "User"."firstName", "Roster"."weekId" AS "Roster.weekId", "Roster"."userId" AS "Roster.userId" FROM "User" AS "User" INNER JOIN "Roster" AS "Roster" ON "User"."id" = "Roster"."weekId" AND "Roster"."userId" = 1;
users count: 5
```

check the database:

```sh
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "User";
 id | firstName
----+-----------
  1 | james
  2 | elsa
  3 | tim
  4 | lee
  5 | jasmine
(5 rows)

node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "Week";
 id |           date
----+---------------------------
  1 | 2020-04-14 01:56:56.55+00
(1 row)

node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "Roster";
 weekId | userId
--------+--------
      1 |      1
      2 |      1
      3 |      1
      4 |      1
      5 |      1
(5 rows)
```

Dependencies versions: `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"`, `postgres:9.6`

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/node-sequelize-examples/tree/master/src/examples/stackoverflow/60805725

Comment: Thank you so much. I've actually learnt so much from your code. Not just the solution to my problem but how the coding techniques as well. Thanks again!